# don't show an images in browser when i press on it after i render-html that

Tags: image, react-native, html-rendering, react-native-webview

In the react app I have to render some html code that contain text, links and some images/videos.

I'm using react-native-render-html for that.

There is a way to let the links open through WebView, but no the Images?

```
<View style={styles.testo_a}>
  <HTML html={this.state.text_} 
    onLinkPress= {(evt, href) => { <WebView source={{href}});/>}} 
    ignoredStyles={['width']}
    staticContentMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width-10}
    imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width-10}/>
</View>
```